# If a set $F$ is closed and $E \subset F$, then $\bar{E} \subset F$

Tags: real-analysis

If a set F is closed and $E \subset F$, then $\bar{E} \subset F$. Note $\bar{E}$ is the closure of $E$. My question is why is $\bar{E}$ strictly a proper subset of $F$? If $F=\bar{E}$, then wouldn't $\bar{E} \subseteq F$?

Comment: You are right, it can be the same set. The symbol "\subset" ($\subset$) is used to indicate a subset, not a proper subset (usually).

Comment: Usually, if people want to be explicit that something is a proper subset, they might write $\subsetneq$ (this is just one of those notational things you have to accept that it is the way it is and move on). You're right though that $\overline{E}$ could either be a proper subset, or be equal to $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$F=[-1,1]$$
$$E_1=(-1,1)$$
$$E_2=(0,1)$$
$$E_3=(-1,1)\cap \Bbb Q$$

then

$$\bar{E_1}=[-1,1]=F$$
$$\bar{E_2}=[0,1]\subset F$$
$$\bar{E_3}=[-1,1]=F$$

Answer (score 0):

The closure of $E,$ $\bar{E},$ is the intersection of the closed sets containing $E.$ Since $F$ is closed and contains $E,$ $\bar{E} \subset F.$